# Data binding issue in angular 6 select dropdowns

Tags: angular, angular6, 2-way-object-databinding

I'm trying to get some data from user from user. My problem is when I try to change value in second dropdown it is changing value in all other rows as well which I'm not expecting to be. 
Lets say I have my view like below with all the second dropdown values set to 'c'. 
[image: initial screen]

When I change any value in second dropdown then it changes in all dropdowns like below
[image]

Please have a look at this link for better understanding.
https://stackblitz.com/edit/angular-a27qru?file=src%2Fapp%2Fapp.component.ts.

Would appreciate if you can provide updated stackblitz link with fix :)

**EDIT**

I don't want to change the data structure, means rowData holds partner and partner contains group inside that.
My condition is that by default it should select 'custom group' as value for first dropdown and some particular value(lets say 'c') from group for 'custom group' value of partner.

Comment: Why are you using `compareWith` in `select`?

Comment: I was playing around with different things in that, I was not calling that method though.

Comment: The problem in your code is, you are using same object in all partners. That's why, whenever you update any value from drop down, that object is getting updated and as all other raw data are using same object, they are also getting updated. Try to utilize Object.assign or Object.create

Comment: Thanks for the comment @shhdharmen, I have tried that before but no luck in that also, anyway I have fixed it, you can check my answer.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Fixed it by changing the data biding to one way binding instead of two way binding in html

See below link for fix reference.

https://stackblitz.com/edit/angular-siktgn?file=src/app/app.component.html

Answer (score 0):

In your `.html` file, replace:

```
<select [(ngModel)]="data.partner.group" class='form-control'>
    <option *ngFor="let option of group" 
    [ngValue]="option">{{option.name}}</option>
</select>
```

by:

```
<select [(ngModel)]="data.group" class='form-control'>
    <option *ngFor="let option2 of group" 
    [ngValue]="option2">{{option2.name}}</option>
</select>
```

Answer (score 0):

link to the updated stackblitz: [answer](https://stackblitz.com/edit/angular-orjyux?file=src%2Fapp%2Fapp.component.ts)